# How to using ABS equivalent in this query formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, unique, google-query-language

The formula converts negative into positive and vice versa, but how can I get all numbers in `Col8` to be positive?

```
=query(UNIQUE(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ddddddddddddsssssssssssssssswwwwwwww/edit";"Sheet1!A1:K"));"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8*-1 where Col2 matches '"&B6&"' label Col8*-1 'Qtd' ")
```

Here's a copy of the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uU9zw9BbXp5hOO1f8fZEcgc8f8u8uZNjoeeuHI3SBpM/edit?usp=sharing)

Would there be an `ABS()` equivalent here?

Thank you!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Just added it to the question, @player0! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(UNIQUE({
 IMPORTRANGE("1uU9zw9BbXp5hOO1f8fZEcgc8f8u8uZNjoeeuHI3SBpM"; "Sheet1!A1:K")\ABS(
 IMPORTRANGE("1uU9zw9BbXp5hOO1f8fZEcgc8f8u8uZNjoeeuHI3SBpM"; "Sheet1!H1:H"))});
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col12 
  where Col1 is not null label Col12'Qty'"))
```

[image]